# How to combine two rows data to one based on the ID

Tags: sql-server-2005

Hi all i am trying out to get the data as per my requirement .the data in my table as follows

```
mpCode in/outMode         date                   time
 5001        0               12/09/2011    09:05:34
5002        0               12/09/2011    09:33:13
5001        1               12/09/2011    18:05:09
5002        1               12/09/2011    17:44:34
```

I would like to get my output as

```
  empCode  date             intime        outtime
  5001       12/09/2011    09:05:34    18:05:09
  5002       12/09/2011    09:33:13    17:44:34
```

Comment: Can you show us what you tried

Comment: All kinds of potential gotchas here... what if the outMode = 1 is missing? What if there are two in/outModes of the same value in a row? What if the out is on the next day (why are the date and time values stored separately)?

Answer (score 0):

Without additional info, a `GROUP BY` is probably the easiest:

```
SELECT   empcode, 
         MAX([date]) as [date], 
         MAX(intime) as [intime], 
         MAX(outtime) as [outtime]
FROM MyTable
GROUP BY empcode
```

Answer (score 0):

As noted aboved there are some gotchas (such as no in/out, in on one day out on the next), but this is as you described.

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#tmp') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE #tmp

GO

CREATE TABLE #tmp (EmpCode INT, InOutMode INT, [DATE] DATETIME, [TIME] DATETIME)

GO

INSERT #tmp (EmpCode,InOutMode,[Date],[TIME])

VALUES (5001,0,'12/09/2011','1/1/1900 09:05:34')
,(5002,0, '12/09/2011','1/1/1900 09:33:13')
,(5001, 1,'12/09/2011','1/1/1900 18:05:09')
,(5002,1 ,'12/09/2011','1/1/1900 17:44:34');

WITH InTime (EmpCode,Date,Time)
AS
(
SELECT
    EmpCode
    ,DATE
    ,TIME
FROM #tmp
WHERE InOutMode = 0
)

SELECT
    t.EmpCode
    ,t.[DATE]
    ,i.[Time]
    ,t.[Time]   
FROM #tmp AS t
JOIN InTime AS i
ON t.EmpCode = i.EmpCode
   AND t.[Date] = i.[Date]
WHERE t.InOutMode = 1
```